# Django_Cron Job Fail

Tags: python, django, cron

I am using django_cron package from
https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron

Its the one that gets installed when you do pip install django_cron

I am able to do everything as instructed. I am getting the cron job to run once when I use python manage.py runcrons

But, the cron jon is not set. The job does not repeat every minute.

The class I have made is as follows:

```
class startPostProcessing(CronJobBase):
    RUN_EVERY_MINS = 1 # every 1 min
    MIN_NUM_FAILURES = 2

    schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
    code = 'random.junk.english.letters.pratik.podddar'    # a unique code

    def do(self):
        ## Code ##
        return
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The documentation says: "Depending on the application the management command can be called from the Unix crontab as often as required". It doesn't seem to be automatic.

Comment: Thanks Paulo. I looked into the codebase as well. That makes sense. I somehow anticipated them to do cron work as well. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score -1):

The documentation says: "Depending on the application the management command can be called from the Unix crontab as often as required". It doesn't seem to be automatic.

The codebase also indicates that.

(Answered in the comments above)

Thanks